# Where can I find a second copy of Great Soul Arrow?

Tags: dark-souls

I'd like to get a second copy of Great Soul Arrow in order to assign it to two attunement slots, but Griggs, the first spell merchant in Firelink Shrine, only seems to have one copy.

How do I find a second?

Answer (score 6):

[Big Hat Logan](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/big-hat-logan) sells a copy as well, and is initially found in a cage within [Sen's Fortress.](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/sen-s-fortress) After getting past the second platform containing swinging blade traps, you'll quickly come across a sleeping snake guard leaning against a wall. Big Hat Logan is located in a room hidden behind this wall, only accessible by breaking the wall.

To break the wall you need to redirect the metal balls you see throughout the fortress. The mechanism to do this is located after the second room with the metal balls coming at you. You want to redirect the mechanism to the hallway opposite the exit which will simply drop the balls off the game map.

In order to unlock the cage he is located in you need one of the following:

- [**Master Key:**](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/master-key) This is a possible starting gift, and the Thief class will always start with it.
- [**Cage Key:**](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/cage-key) This is located further on in the fortress, shortly before fighting the boss. On your way to the boss you'll notice that part of the bridge is broken. If you jump over this (dash + action button) you'll find yourself in a tower with a merchant, and at the bottom of the tower you'll find the cage key.

After you free him from the cage he'll return to Firelink Shrine, where he'll start selling spells. He'll stay there until you put the [Lordvessel](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/lordvessel) on the [Firelink Altar](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/firelink-altar), at which point he'll relocate to [The Duke's Archives](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/the-duke-s-archives). Make you sure buy his copy of Great Soul Arrow before he moves, since he won't become a merchant again until after you've gone through a large portion of The Duke's Archives.

Comment: Also note that he may not sell to you, even if you release him from his cage. I released him and spoke to him, but he basically said 'Some people just can't learn sorcery" and I can't purchase from him. I haven't been able to find the conditions that trigger this.

Comment: @EvilAmarant7x that's just because you need 10 INT. To learn any spell you need 10 points in the related stat.

Comment: Nope, that's not true. I have 10 Int and can learn spells from his apprentice. Although it is true that I didn't have 10 Int the first time I talked to him, so it could be that his willingness is locked on initial conversation. Or something else.

Comment: He'll only sell to you when he returns to firelink, as stated in my answer.

Comment: I'm telling you, he's sitting there, right next to his apprentice in Firelink and refuses to sell to me. Other people have had the same issue: http://www.gamespot.com/ps3/rpg/dark-souls/answers.html?qid=295013

Comment: @EvilAmarant7x You have to have at least 15 int for BHL to teach you.

Comment: +1 Because I hate it when the OP doesn't return to make an answer correct.